# Using Spark with already implemented logging mechanism?

Tags: java, apache-spark, logging, stack-overflow

I have a really huge application which does all of its logging against its own logging mechanism that derived from java.util.logging.

Now, I'd like to add some classes which use Spark for some statistical computation, and Spark uses log4j/slf4j for logging.

When I try to debug/run this application now, I'm getting StackOverflow error because logging mechanism of application and slf4j continuously calling each other.

I feel somehow familiar with the built-in JDK logging available with java.util.logging, 
I tried to change some settings in Spark's configuration and tried to override log4j.properties file but it hasn't solved the problem.

Is there any easy way to disable Spark's logging mechanism or somehow bridge this to logging libraries?

I tried in SparkConf:

```
.set("spark.eventlog.enabled", "false")
.set("spark.logConf", "false")
```

I am getting StackOverFlow error on the line:

```
SparkSession spark = sparkBuilder.getOrCreate();
```

The stack trace is like this: (actually it is much more longer as you can guess)

```
Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.companyName.afc.action.InvokeAction.throwCause(InvokeAction.java:209)
    at com.companyName.afc.action.InvokeAction.invoke(InvokeAction.java:166)
    at com.companyName.afc.action.InvokeAction.actionPerformed(InvokeAction.java:138)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.fillCallerData(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:602)
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:587)
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:588)
at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:660)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
```

Comment: Can you please include the error stack trace?

Comment: @shriyog, I added the error stack trace.

Comment: It seems when I use **slf4j-nop** without test scope specification, this problem is solved.